# Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 0, column 0 ajax in the datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I can not show the data with Ajax, I get the error:

> Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 0, column 0

HTML

```html
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

PHP

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$columns = '{"data": [';
$columns .= '{"name": "1234567890", "surname": "test"}, ';
$columns .= '{"name": "8200469963", "surname": "amit"}';
$columns .= ']}';
die(json_encode($columns));
```

JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "processing" : true ,
        "serverSide" : true ,
        "ajax": {
            type: 'POST',
            url: "data.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "surname" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple problems with your code:

- Invalid DataTables initialization settings `serverSide: true` and `dataSrc: ""` for your response structure.
- PHP script is encoding into JSON twice.

Use the following PHP script as a template:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data = [
   'data' => [
      [
         'name' => '1234567890',
         'surname' => 'test'
      ],
      [
         'name' => '8200469963',
         'surname' => 'amit'
      ],
   ]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Use the following initialization options:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "ajax": {
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "surname" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your PHP code:

1. Your `$columns` variable is a string, which you're trying to encode as a JSON - this will not produce what you're expecting at all.  You should create it as an object and then encode:

   ```
   $columns = ["data" => [
       ["name" => "1234567890", "surname" => "test"],
       ["name" => "8200469963", "surname" => "amit"]
   ]];
   ```
2. Don't use `die` - this may cause undesired effect on the server-side. Use `echo` instead:

   ```
   echo json_encode($columns);
   ```

So, in its entirety, your PHP code would be:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$columns = ["data" => [
    ["name" => "1234567890", "surname" => "test"],
    ["name" => "8200469963", "surname" => "amit"]
]];

echo json_encode($columns);
```